# Wordpress wp_title с большой буквы

Tags: wordpress

Занимаюсь настройкой SEO в wordpress без плагинов.

Есть тег

```
wp_title();
```

Вопрос как сделать в выводимом им тексте, первую букву заглавной?

Без большой буквы получается не очень

```
тест | Результаты поиска | Site.com
```

Как решить данную проблему, не пойму, на англ сайтах смотрел, пишут что нужно убрать все фильтры, убрал, обвернул в ucfirst, результата ноль.

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с версии 4.4, функция wp_title() считается устаревшей. Используйте wp_get_document_title() - она возвращает строку заголовка, с которой вы можете делать все, что захотите, в том числе и установить первую букву заглавной.

```
$title = wp_get_document_title();
$title = ucfirst($title);
echo $title;
```

Comment: К сожалению ucfirst не срабатывает и в вами приведенном коде.

Comment: Слушайте, вы меня поставили в тупик своим комментарием. Я даже вынужден был сделать тестовый пример и проверить этот код. Конечно, работает! Давайте-ка, согласно правилам сообщества, создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Дело в том, что вы не так поняли, мне нужно с большой буквы, отобразить query поиска,  а не все что входит в wp_get_document_title();

Comment: Дело в том, что согласно правилам сообщества, без кода тут вообще не принято разговаривать.

Comment: Какой код вам нужен ? я привел не код, а функцию которая выводит, текст, вводимый в форму поиска. Текст она выводит с маленькой буквы, если я пишу с маленькой, и на оборот. Задача сделать так, что бы когда человек писал с маленькой, текст в тайтле подставлялся с Заглавной. К примеру при индексации поиска будет смотреться красиво и понятно.

Comment: Прочитайте правила сообщества. Я дал вам ссылку. А за разговорным жанром проследуйте в соцсети.

Comment: Хорошо, вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Несмотря на то, что данный код якобы "не работает" ответ является правильным при текущем объеме предоставленных данных. Ответу плюс без галки, вопрос закрыть как "нет кода", топикстартера отправить писать минимально воспроизводимый пример.